# Stopping a cookie from being deleted when the browser is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have addded a plugin to my cms "quick.cms" - simple notice about use cookies.
This script throw an information at every entrance, i want to script check cookie and display information only first visit. Check: duka-polska.pl, after closing browser the information display again.

```
 function simpleNotice( sNotice ){
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var bCookiesNoticeClosed = throwCookie( 'bCookiesNoticeClosed' );
    if( !bCookiesNoticeClosed && sNotice != '' ){
      $( 'body' ).prepend( '<div id="noticeAboutCookies">'+sNotice+'<a href="#" class="close">[x]</a></div>' );
      jQuery("#noticeAboutCookies").delay(1000).slideToggle("slow");
      jQuery("#noticeAboutCookies .close").click(function(){
        jQuery("#noticeAboutCookies").delay(500).slideUp("slow")
        createCookie( 'bCookiesNoticeClosed', true );
        return false;
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided the code for `createCookie`, but there is no sign of a time stamp there. If you set a cookie without an expiry time, then it expires when the browser is closed.

Set an expiry time on the cookie.

Comment: in this line createCookie( 'bCookiesNoticeClosed', true ); ? What you sugest 7 days ? or more ?

Comment: It's up to you. Would you be distracted by site, reminding you about cookies every week?

Comment: it works :) i have set up 180 days. But i have question how to do a name of cookies be example liquid84(today date) ?